# Find which config file Apache uses to find virtual host

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have a rather complicated Apache setup: some config files have to be manually written and some have to be automatically generated. So far, I've had no problems. But now, I've just tried to set a site at:

```
newsubdomain.mydomain.com
```

and Apache directs it to the data for:

```
www.someotherdomain.com
```

I've looking into all the many config files and can't find anything wrong. All is pointing where it should and no definitions, as far as I can tell, overlap.

Is there a way to see which config files or config instructions Apache is using to match a URL to a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. An automatically generated config file was never read. All fixed now.